# Unable to mount 3rd partition from img file

Tags: linux, partitioning, mount

I have an `img` file which has 3 partitions and looks like below

```
$ fdisk -l ./disk.img 
Disk ./disk.img: 4 GiB, 4294967296 bytes, 8388608 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x90909090

Device     Boot   Start     End Sectors  Size Id Type
./disk.img            1  131072  131072   64M ef EFI (FAT-12/16/32)
./disk.img *     131073 1761232 1630160  796M a5 FreeBSD
./disk.img      1761233 8388607 6627375  3.2G  b W95 FAT32
```

I tried below command to mount but it does not work.

```
sudo mount -o loop,rw,sync,offset=$((1761233*512)) ./disk.img /mnt/usb
```

Below is the output after the mount.  The size of the partition it shows as 63MB where I was expecting it to be close to 3.2G.

```
$ df -h scratch/usb/
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/loop6       63M   16K   63M   1% /mnt/usb
```

Output of `losetup -la` is below

```
$ sudo losetup -la
NAME       SIZELIMIT    OFFSET AUTOCLEAR RO BACK-FILE                                                              DIO LOG-SEC
/dev/loop1         0         0         1  1 /var/lib/snapd/snaps/core18_2714.snap                                    0     512
/dev/loop6         0 901751296         1  0 /home/naidu/disk.img   0     512
/dev/loop4         0         0         1  1 /var/lib/snapd/snaps/snapd_17950.snap                                    0     512
/dev/loop2         0         0         1  1 /var/lib/snapd/snaps/docker_2343.snap                                    0     512
/dev/loop0         0         0         1  1 /var/lib/snapd/snaps/core18_2708.snap                                    0     512
/dev/loop5         0         0         1  1 /var/lib/snapd/snaps/snapd_18357.snap                                    0     512
/dev/loop3         0         0         1  1 /var/lib/snapd/snaps/docker_2746.snap                                    0     512
```

Output of the `parted` command is below

```
$ sudo parted ./disk.img print
Model:  (file)
Disk /home/naidu/disk.img: 4295MB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End     Size    Type     File system  Flags
 1      512B    67.1MB  67.1MB  primary  fat16        esp
 2      67.1MB  902MB   835MB   primary               boot
 3      902MB   4295MB  3393MB  primary  fat32
```

Out of `dd if=/home/naidu/disk.img bs=512 skip=1761233 count=2 2>/dev/null | gzip -c -9 | base64` command

```
H4sIAAAAAAACA3sdMcEp2MVEz0RBgYGJEYgZgOADA4M9gwADBDAxfGCGsRgYGCEqEIBRU0ymZn+A
W7CrX7CrAhC4OYYYGwHpX4YH+i7sYaj53XfjBQNDXPMxyd3sDH/WtBwoYdvCd1bg9VeDJ2fFzkry
cvnl5+kWVxaXpOYqpGQWZ/NyBRSlFhcrJOZVKmSnViqU5CsUpSbl55fwcjGMAuqC0FVBQYmOo+Ew
vEFRkWPi/e+MDLZY4h8At2s1TgAEAAA=
```

I also have below output if this gives more clues and ways to fix it

```
$ gdisk -l ./disk.img 
GPT fdisk (gdisk) version 1.0.8

Partition table scan:
  MBR: MBR only
  BSD: not present
  APM: not present
  GPT: not present


***************************************************************
Found invalid GPT and valid MBR; converting MBR to GPT format
in memory. 
***************************************************************

Warning! Main partition table overlaps the first partition by 33 blocks!
You will need to delete this partition or resize it in another utility.

Warning! Secondary partition table overlaps the last partition by
33 blocks!
You will need to delete this partition or resize it in another utility.
Disk ./disk.img: 8388608 sectors, 4.0 GiB
Sector size (logical): 512 bytes
Disk identifier (GUID): 36F01765-7E55-4F88-B946-DD584C8034AC
Partition table holds up to 128 entries
Main partition table begins at sector 2 and ends at sector 33
First usable sector is 34, last usable sector is 8388574
Partitions will be aligned on 1-sector boundaries
Total free space is 0 sectors (0 bytes)

Number  Start (sector)    End (sector)  Size       Code  Name
   1               1          131072   64.0 MiB    EF00  EFI system partition
   2          131073         1761232   796.0 MiB   A500  FreeBSD disklabel
   3         1761233         8388607   3.2 GiB     0700  Microsoft basic data
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Try [this script](https://askubuntu.com/a/499143/963426).

Comment: It is doing the same thing but from the script.  I still see 63M after the mount.

Comment: It looks as if you're mounting the EFI partition.

Comment: In general (a fragment of) a block device or (of) a regular file may hold a partition that is smaller. *Maybe* the filesystem at the desired offset is indeed so small. What is the relevant line in the output of `losetup -la`?

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski do you want me to add `img` file name to the `losetup` command?  if I dont then the output is not much relevant.

Comment: @JoepvanSteen i agree.  it looks indeed like that but the mount command does not say so.  It explicitly mentions the offset which needs to be mounted.  Seems like it is getting ignored.

Comment: When `df` shows you a line that starts with `/dev/loop6`, I expect the output of `losetup -la` to  contain a line that also starts with `/dev/loop6`.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski I unmounted and therefore output of /dev/loop6 was not shown.  Have mounted it and added the output the original question now.

Comment: @FenrisLycaon added the output to the original quesiton

Comment: The output of `losetup -la` shows the offset was passed all right. Maybe the filesystem is indeed way smaller than the partition. Please post the output of `dd if=/home/naidu/disk.img bs=512 skip=1761233 count=2 2>/dev/null | gzip -c -9 | base64`

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski added to the original question

Comment: @FenrisLycaon whats the solution?  How to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You posted base64-coded gzipped content of the first two sectors of the partition. Let's decode, gunzip and see what `file` says:

```
<<EOF base64 -d | gzip -cd | file -
H4sIAAAAAAACA3sdMcEp2MVEz0RBgYGJEYgZgOADA4M9gwADBDAxfGCGsRgYGCEqEIBRU0ymZn+A
W7CrX7CrAhC4OYYYGwHpX4YH+i7sYaj53XfjBQNDXPMxyd3sDH/WtBwoYdvCd1bg9VeDJ2fFzkry
cvnl5+kWVxaXpOYqpGQWZ/NyBRSlFhcrJOZVKmSnViqU5CsUpSbl55fwcjGMAuqC0FVBQYmOo+Ew
vEFRkWPi/e+MDLZY4h8At2s1TgAEAAA=
EOF
```

This is the output:

```
/dev/stdin: DOS/MBR boot sector, code offset 0x58+2, OEM-ID "BSD4.4  ", sectors/track 63, heads 16, sectors 131072 (volumes > 32 MB), FAT (32 bit), sectors/FAT 1008, reserved 0x1, serial number 0xbf7c1c16, label: "PFSENSE    "
```

`sectors 131072` means the filesystem takes 131072x512 bytes; this is exactly 64 MiB. In the filesystem there are metadata and structures, so `63M` you got from `df -h` seems quite right as the size for data.

Conclusion: what you have mounted is *the* filesystem. The filesystem is way smaller than the partition.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.  Makes sense now.  I did `fatresize` on 3rd partition but seems it really did not.  Any pointers on how to grow the partition to maximum size? I am doing this in ubuntu via a shell script.

Comment: @BTRNaidu One question per question please. Your question is "what am I missing here?" and I believe I have answered this. You can ask a new (follow-up) question separately. Link to the question above to provide context. In the new question post the exact `fatresize` command you used. "I did `fatresize` on 3rd partition" is vague; besides, when we work with an image, there is no 3rd partition as a file, unless we know how to proceed, so clarification is needed about what you did. Posting the exact command should make some things clear.

Comment: Posted the question here [link](https://superuser.com/questions/1775244/not-able-to-grow-the-partition-in-img-file)