# Not able to resize the filesystem within an img file

Tags: linux, ubuntu, partitioning

I have an `img` file with below partition table

```
$ sudo parted /tmp/disk.img 
GNU Parted 3.4
Using /tmp/disk.img
Welcome to GNU Parted! Type 'help' to view a list of commands.
(parted) print                                                            
Model:  (file)
Disk /tmp/disk.img: 969MB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End     Size    Type     File system  Flags
 1      512B    67.1MB  67.1MB  primary  fat16        esp
 2      67.1MB  902MB   835MB   primary               boot
 3      902MB   969MB   67.1MB  primary  fat32
```

I need to increase the disk image so that it can accommodate larger file.  To increase the disk image size, I first added more space using `qemu-img` and then extend the 3rd partition with the available free space.

```
$ sudo qemu-img resize disk.img 4G
WARNING: Image format was not specified for 'disk.img' and probing guessed raw.
         Automatically detecting the format is dangerous for raw images, write operations on block 0 will be restricted.
         Specify the 'raw' format explicitly to remove the restrictions.
Image resized.
$
$ sudo parted disk.img print
Model:  (file)
Disk /home/naidu/up/chris/upwork-sample/disk.img: 4295MB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End     Size    Type     File system  Flags
 1      512B    67.1MB  67.1MB  primary  fat16        esp
 2      67.1MB  902MB   835MB   primary               boot
 3      902MB   969MB   67.1MB  primary  fat32
$
$ sudo parted disk.img resizepart 3 100%
$ 
$ sudo parted disk.img print
Model:  (file)
Disk /home/naidu/up/chris/upwork-sample/disk.img: 4295MB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End     Size    Type     File system  Flags
 1      512B    67.1MB  67.1MB  primary  fat16        esp
 2      67.1MB  902MB   835MB   primary               boot
 3      902MB   4295MB  3393MB  primary  fat32

$
$ sudo losetup --show -f disk.img 
/dev/loop4
$ sudo partprobe -s /dev/loop4
/dev/loop4: msdos partitions 1 2 3
$ sudo fatresize  /dev/loop4 -n 3 -s 4G -i -p -v
fatresize 1.1.0 (20201114)
.part(start=1761233, end=8388607, length=6627375)
FAT: fat32
Cur size: 67108864
Min size: 67141632
Max size: 4294967296
$ 
$ sudo parted disk.img print
Model:  (file)
Disk /home/naidu/up/chris/upwork-sample/disk.img: 4295MB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End     Size    Type     File system  Flags
 1      512B    67.1MB  67.1MB  primary  fat16        esp
 2      67.1MB  902MB   835MB   primary               boot
 3      902MB   4295MB  3393MB  primary  fat32

$
```

After successful `fatresize`, one would assume that the 3rd partition is extended but it seems not as verified by below post [link](https://superuser.com/questions/1775110/unable-to-mount-3rd-partition-from-img-file/).

Anyone has some idea on how to successfully resize the 3rd partition?  I need to do this via shell script.  Therefore gui programs like `gparted` is not an option.

Based on suggestion from one of the possible answers, I altered the command `fatresize` and it crashed -

```
$ sudo lsblk /dev/loop6
NAME  MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINTS
loop6   7:6    0  3.2G  0 loop /tmp/usb
$
$ sudo fatresize  /dev/loop6 -s 3235M  -p -v
fatresize 1.1.0 (20201114)
.part(start=0, end=6627374, length=6627375)
Backtrace has 6 calls on stack:
  6: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libparted.so.2(ped_assert+0x53) [0x7f97e6aa09a3]
  5: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libparted.so.2(ped_geometry_read+0) [0x7f97e6aa7010]
  4: fatresize(+0x306a) [0x5577373c006a]
  3: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x29d90) [0x7f97e6893d90]
  2: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0x80) [0x7f97e6893e40]
  1: fatresize(+0x353e) [0x5577373c053e]
Bug: Assertion (disk != NULL) at ../../libparted/disk.c:1620 in function ped_disk_get_partition_by_sector() failed.
Aborted
$
```

Comment: "After successful fatresize" - How can you tell?

Comment: @JoepvanSteen because the command does not give any error?

Comment: But it was determined the file system was *not* resized, correct? https://superuser.com/a/1775213/705502

Comment: Correct.  Therefore a new question on how to resize it.

Answer (score 1):

Updated answer: I think the main problem is not being able to work on each partition independently, fatresize appears to need some more work on it's partition operations.

I would use either `losetup -P` or `kpartx` to assign each partition to it's own loop device, then tell `fatresize` to only work on the 3rd partition's specific device (probably something like /dev/loop0p3 but check the setup command's output, or `losetup -a`). That should let it auto-detect the correct sizes from `-i` and maybe even let `-s max` work.

- See https://askubuntu.com/questions/69363/mount-single-partition-from-image-of-entire-disk-device for more info on mounting a multi-partition disk image

---

I spotted a couple issues:

- Looks like adding the `-i` flag to your `fatrezise` command cause it to only output the volume info, and not actually do any resizing. Try it again without the `-i`.

  - Result: still didn't work, fatresize didn't like the sizes
- The whole container file `disk.img` was resized to 4G (GiB), while fatresize's `-i` information seems to think the last partition's `Max size: 4294967296` (which is 4G in bytes) - which is the whole size of the entire container, not just the 3rd partition. That appears to be a bug, so I'm not confident `fatresize` can operate on only the 3rd partition. (And the 1st and 3rd partitions were originally the same size too, adding more potential confusion whether or not fatresize is looking at the 1st or 3rd partition.)

  1. Using the info from `parted` for the 3rd partition's size 3393MB should work better, if `fatreize` accepts `-s 3393MB`. It's not in the same conversion/format however, but if fatresize accepts MB's that's ok, or converting it to M/MiB it should be about 3393MB * 1000 * 1000 = 3393000000 bytes, then / by 1024 a few times it should get to just over 3235M, so `-s 3235M`
  2. Or, ask `parted` to use `"B" (bytes)` with it's `unit` command, then tell fatresize the bytes size of the 3rd partition.

  (My version of `fatresize` didn't have the `-n` option at all, so I would have had to get the kernel to see the individual partitions and then operate on only the 3rd partition).

Comment: without -i, I get the error ```fatresize 1.1.0 (20201114)
.part(start=1761233, end=8388607, length=6627375)
Error: The location 4902MB is outside of the device /dev/loop4.```

Comment: With option `-s max`, i get the error `Error: The location 5197MB is outside of the device /dev/loop4.`

Comment: I got similar errors when I tried creating a small test FAT filesystem inside a single file... fatresize wasn't very intuitive. And the stable/oldstable version I tested didn't have the `-n` option either. I just spotted another error, I"ll edit my answer

Comment: `fatresize` crashes with I supply `-s 3235M` as parameter.  Have added the output the original question.

Comment: That's definitely a bug in fatresize (assuming the file/disk is even readable/writeable and the loop device is set up correct). An older/stable version might work? Or check what `fatresize -i` says for the maximum size and try that, or try it's `-s max` option?

Comment: `-s max` also aborts with an Assert.  Same crash.

Comment: Unless there's a problem with the filesystem (checked it with `fsck.fat`?) or reading the file, fixing bugs are outside of my wheelhouse. Pretty much a showstopper, and  fatresize, appears to be the only command line tool that's handy. Gparted should be able to resize fat partitions, but it's a GUI, and  parted doesn't want to touch filesystems. A workaround could be copying the files somewhere else, create a new filesystem, then copy the files back (if there's space somewhere else)

Comment: `fsck.fat` gives below output.  ```$ sudo fsck.vfat disk.img 
fsck.fat 4.2 (2021-01-31)
Logical sector size (48764 bytes) is not a multiple of the physical sector size.```

Comment: I don't think `fatresize` is working well for either of us. I tried testing it with a loop file, it said "Illegal new volume size" when I told it to use it's own suggested max size, then it apparently couldn't see other loop devices (telling it to look at /dev/loop2: "Error: Could not stat device /dev/loop - No such file or directory." - /dev/loop is not /dev/loop2! I am testing with the oldstable 1.0.2, but it seems a little too buggy to be relied upon